# ¿Cómo puedo declarar muchas variables de una sola vez?

Tags: javascript

soy algo nuevo en JavaScript y quiero simplificar este código para mi página HTML, todo me apunta a que hay algún modo más eficiente para hacer esto, pero no se me ocurre cómo.

```js
var loginButton = document.getElementById("show-login-button");
var loginPanel = document.getElementById("login");
var regButton = document.getElementById("show-register-button");
var register = document.getElementById("register");
var editter1 = document.getElementById("edit-1");
var editter2 = document.getElementById("edit-2");
var editter3 = document.getElementById("edit-3");
var editter4 = document.getElementById("edit-4");
var editter5 = document.getElementById("edit-5");
var editter6 = document.getElementById("edit-6");
var editter7 = document.getElementById("edit-7");
var editter8 = document.getElementById("edit-8");   
var editter9 = document.getElementById("edit-9");
var editter10 = document.getElementById("edit-10");
var editter11 = document.getElementById("edit-11");
var editter12 = document.getElementById("edit-12");
var editter13 = document.getElementById("edit-13");
var editter14 = document.getElementById("edit-14");
var editter15 = document.getElementById("edit-15");
var editter16 = document.getElementById("edit-16");
var editter17 = document.getElementById("edit-17");
var editter18 = document.getElementById("edit-18");
var editter19 = document.getElementById("edit-19");
var editter20 = document.getElementById("edit-20");
var editter21 = document.getElementById("edit-21");
var editter22 = document.getElementById("edit-22");
var editter23 = document.getElementById("edit-23");
var editter24 = document.getElementById("edit-24");
var editter25 = document.getElementById("edit-25");
var editter26 = document.getElementById("edit-26");
var editter27 = document.getElementById("edit-27");
var editter28 = document.getElementById("edit-28");
var editter29 = document.getElementById("edit-29");
var editter30 = document.getElementById("edit-30");
var editter31 = document.getElementById("edit-31");
var editter32 = document.getElementById("edit-32");
var editter33 = document.getElementById("edit-33");
var editter34 = document.getElementById("edit-34");
var editter35 = document.getElementById("edit-35");

function editElement(MyElement){
    var ownElement = document.getElementById(MyElement);
    ownElement.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
    ownElement.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
};

function showElement(){
    if (register.style.display == "block" && loginPanel.style.display == "none") {
        loginPanel.style.display = "block";
        register.style.display = "none";
    } else if (loginPanel.style.display == "block"){
        loginPanel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        loginPanel.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function showRegister(){
    if (loginPanel.style.display == "block" && register.style.display == "none"){
        loginPanel.style.display = "none";
        register.style.display = "block";
    } else if (register.style.display == "block") {
        register.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        register.style.display = "block";
    }
};

loginButton.addEventListener("click", showElement);
regButton.addEventListener("click", showRegister);

editter1?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-1")});
editter2?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-2")});
editter3?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-3")});
editter4?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-4")});
editter5?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-5")});
editter6?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-6")});
editter7?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-7")});
editter8?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-8")});
editter9?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-9")});
editter10?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-10")});
editter11?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-11")});
editter12?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-12")});
editter13?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-13")});
editter14?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-14")});
editter15?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-15")});
editter16?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-16")});
editter17?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-17")});
editter18?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-18")});
editter19?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-19")});
editter20?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-20")});
editter21?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-21")});
editter22?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-22")});
editter23?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-23")});
editter24?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-24")});
editter25?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-25")});
editter26?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-26")});
editter27?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-27")});
editter28?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-28")});
editter29?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-29")});
editter30?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-30")});
editter31?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-31")});
editter32?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-32")});
editter33?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-33")});
editter34?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-34")});
editter35?.addEventListener("click", function(){editElement("editable-35")});
```

Intenté usar un for pero no se me ocurre cómo ponerle el nombre a la variable. ¿Es posible hacerlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar una [*clase*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) para agrupar a todos los elmentos del mismo tipo, no es necesario ponerle un identificador a cada uno, a menos que requieras realmente un elemento diferenciado de los demás.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const editableElements = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');

function onClickHandler(event) {
  event.currentTarget.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
  event.currentTarget.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
  event.currentTarget.style.borderColor = "red";
};

for(let i = 0; i < editableElements.length; ++i) {
  editableElements.item(i).addEventListener("click", onClickHandler);
}
```

```css
.editable {
  padding: .3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable">Uno</div>
<div class="editable">Dos</div>
<div class="editable">Tres</div>
<div class="editable">Cuatro</div>
<div class="editable">Cinco</div>
<div class="editable">Seis</div>
<div class="editable">Siete</div>
<div class="editable">Ocho</div>
<div class="editable">Nueve</div>
<div class="editable">Diez</div>
```

Con esto, recorres la colección de elementos que quieres hacer editables, y en una sola linea le asignas a todos el manejador para el evento `click`, que aplicará los estilos y atributos escogidos.

Si deseas volver al estado inicial todos los elementos excepto aquel en el que has hecho click, podrías hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```js
const editableElements = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');

function toggleEditable(element, editable) {
  if(editable) {
    element.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
    element.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
    element.style.borderColor = "red";
    return;
  }
  element.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
  element.style.borderStyle = "solid";
  element.style.borderColor = "black";
}

function onClickHandler(event) {
  for(let i = 0; i < editableElements.length; ++i) {
    toggleEditable(editableElements.item(i), i === event.currentTarget.indexClicked);
  }
};

for(let i = 0; i < editableElements.length; ++i) {
  editableElements.item(i).indexClicked = i;
  editableElements.item(i).addEventListener("click", onClickHandler);
}
```

```css
.editable {
  padding: .3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editable">Uno</div>
<div class="editable">Dos</div>
<div class="editable">Tres</div>
<div class="editable">Cuatro</div>
<div class="editable">Cinco</div>
<div class="editable">Seis</div>
<div class="editable">Siete</div>
<div class="editable">Ocho</div>
<div class="editable">Nueve</div>
<div class="editable">Diez</div>
```

En este código uso una función llamada `toggleEditable` que recibe un elemento y un valor booleano, que indica si el elemento debe hacerse editable o no.

De esta forma, cada vez que se hace clic en un elemento, el mismo se hará editable y los demás se harán no editables.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver problema.

Answer (score 1):

Una mejor manera de Manejar eventos cuando los elementos tienen sintaxis en comun es apañarce/aplicar ciclos que adiciones los eventos y manejen los trigger.

Te dejo este ejemplo:

```
var loginButton = document.getElementById("show-login-button");
var loginPanel = document.getElementById("login");
var regButton = document.getElementById("show-register-button");
var register = document.getElementById("register");

function showElement() {
    if (register.style.display === "block") {
        register.style.display = "none";
        loginPanel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        loginPanel.style.display = (loginPanel.style.display === "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }
}

function editElement(id) {
    var ownElement = document.getElementById(id);
    ownElement.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
    ownElement.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
}

loginButton.addEventListener("click", showElement);
regButton.addEventListener("click", showElement);

for (let i = 1; i <= 35; i++) {
    var editter = document.getElementById(`edit-${i}`);
    if (editter) {
        editter.addEventListener("click", function () {
            editElement(`editable-${i}`);
        });
    }
}
```

no he probado el codigo posiblemente tenga errores pero no tengo un html a mano como para poder agregar y ver la funcionalidad. adapta la solucion a tu necesidad. como veras depende del ciclo for que va de 1 a 35, apegandome a tu ejemplo.

pro otro lado si no sabes la cantidad de ejementos editables, por lo tanto es desconocidos entonces nos aremos del uso de `querySelectorAll` para acceder a todos los elementos mediante un query al dom... quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
var loginButton = document.getElementById("show-login-button");
var loginPanel = document.getElementById("login");
var regButton = document.getElementById("show-register-button");
var register = document.getElementById("register");

function showElement() {
    if (register.style.display === "block") {
        register.style.display = "none";
        loginPanel.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        loginPanel.style.display = (loginPanel.style.display === "block") ? "none" : "block";
    }
}

function editElement(el) {
    el.setAttribute("contenteditable", "");
    el.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
}

loginButton.addEventListener("click", showElement);
regButton.addEventListener("click", showElement);

var editableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".editable");
editableElements.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function () {
        editElement(el);
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: para eso estamos.